# Prove $A^{T}$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, diagonalization

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Prove that if $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A^T$ is also diagonalizable.

By definition, since $A$ is diagonalizable,

$A = P^{-1} B P$, where $B$ is a diagonal matrix and $P$ is an invertible matrix.

$A^T = P^T B^T (P^{-1})^T$

$B^T$ is a diagonal matrix by definition, we have $(P^{-1})^T = (P^T)^{-1}$, let $D = P^{-1}$ then, $A^T = DB^T D^{-1}$ where $B^T$ is diagonal, thus $A^T$ is diagonalizable by definition

Does this work?

Comment: yes, that works

Comment: A diagonal matrix is a matrix having zeroes off diagonal, and the traspose changes the item $(i, j)$ for the item $(j, i),$ notice that if $j = i,$ there is no change.

Answer (score 2):

This works.

Here is another approach. Recall that a matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial $\mu_A(t)$ is a product of distinct linear factors. Since $\mu_{A}(t)=\mu_{A^\top}(t)$, it follows that $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if $A^\top$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider determinant:

$\det(A)=\det(A^T)$

$(A-\lambda I)^T=(A^T-\lambda I)$ since $I$ is symmetric.

So we get: $\det(A-\lambda I)^T=\det(A^T-\lambda I)=\det(A-\lambda I)$,

Which means that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues, $\lambda$.

Comment: This is true but not enough to prove what is asked. You either need the argument given by the OP or the argument using minimal polynomials given in the other answer.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I don't see what is missing in my proof.

Comment: "$X$ and $Y$ have the same eigenvalues" is not the same property as "If $X$ is diagonalisable so is $Y$".